# If $(X,| \cdot|)$ is isometrically isomorphic with $(X,\|\cdot \|)$ is it always true that the norms are equivalent??

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,|\cdot|)$ and $(X,\| \cdot\|)$ be normed vector spaces and $T:X\to X$ an *isometric isomorphism*. Is it true that the norms $| \cdot |$ and $\|\cdot \|$ are equivalent? I think in general case that DOES not hold but I am not pretty sure. Any conditions to make this be true?

Edit: An idea is when $\dim X<+\infty$ where all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Isometry means $\|x\|=|x|$. Equivalent means $a|x|\le \|x\|\le b|x|$. So isometry implies equivalent, but not the other way round.

Comment: Just take $|x|$ and $2|x|$. Equivalent but not isometric.

Comment: I cannot understand you.You say that isometry⟹norms are equivalent but you can find a normed space X in which you have 2 equivalent norms but X with one norm is not isometric with X with the other norm(opposite site does not hold)?

Comment: @Chrystomath Actually, $|x|$ and $2|x|$ are isometric, as there is an isometry $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}x$.

Comment: Yes but those norms are equivalent aswell im asking if a chance that does not happen

Comment: @Chrystomath Come to think of it, isometry doesn't mean $\|x\| = |x|$, it means there is a surjective linear map $T : X \to X$ such that $\|Tx\| = |x|$. This question is not as trivial as it first looks.

Comment: It's not quite the same question, but the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613034/can-a-vector-space-be-complete-for-two-non-compatible-norms) also answers your question. (No, the two norms need not be equivalent.)

Comment: @user810049 i agree with you totally its wrong what he is trying to say but now i am a bit confused because the T:X--->X is the id function;

Comment: @DanielFischer yes this answers my question so in general case this does not hold.I am now more confused because since T:X--->X is isometry is it true that the norm ||T||=1?

Comment: @GeorgeGiatilis The norm of any isometry on a non-trivial space is $1$, which follows directly from the definition.

Comment: Norms need not be  equivalent .But since T:X--->X is an isometry its wrong to suppose that T=I as @Chrystomath did?This confused me even more because i tried as you said $||Tx||=|x|$  and not $||x||=|x|$

Comment: You're misrepresenting things. To say that norms, mappings, and spaces are isometric mean different things. Yes, $|x|$ and $2|x|$ are not isometric as norms, though their spaces have an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @Chrystomath I've never heard of norms being isometric. If $\|x\| = |x|$ for all $x$, then I'd say $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\cdot|$ are "the same" or "equal".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ has two norms, $\|\cdot\|$ and $|\cdot|$, then:

1. **It is possible for the norms to be equivalent but the spaces are not isometrically isomorphic.**

For example, let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with 1-norm and 2-norm. These norms are equivalent $$\|x\|_2\le\|x\|_1\le\sqrt{2}\|x\|_2$$ but only the 2-norm satisfies the parallelogram law. If $T:X_1\to X_2$ were an isometric isomorphism, $\|Tx\|_2=\|x\|_1$, then for $x=(1,1)$, $y=(1,-1)$, $$\|x+y\|_1^2+\|x-y\|_1^2=8<16=2\|x\|_1^2+2\|y\|_1^2$$ yet $$\|Tx+Ty\|_2^2+\|Tx-Ty\|_2^2=2\|Tx\|_2^2+2\|Ty\|_2^2$$ gives a contradiction.

2. **It is possible for the norms to be inequivalent but the spaces are isometrically isomorphic.**

Let $X$ be a (infinite-dimensional) normed space. Take any bijective but unbounded linear map $T:X\to X$. Then it is trivial to check that $\|Tx\|$ is a norm; call it $|x|:=\|Tx\|$, so $T$ becomes an isometric isomorphism. But the norms are inequivalent, for $|x|\le c\|x\|$ would imply that $T$ is bounded$$\|Tx\|=|x|\le c\|x\|$$

For a specific example, take $X=c_{00}$ with the $\infty$-norm and $T(a_n)=(na_n)$. So $\|(a_n)\|=\max_n|a_n|$, $|(a_n)|=\max_nn|a_n|$. Then $X_{\|\cdot\|}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X_{|\cdot|}$ via $T$, but the norms are not equivalent $$|e_n|=n\not\le c\|e_n\|$$

[In finite dimensions, any two norms are equivalent.]

Comment: In your second point, you might want to clarify that $X$ is a normed space and you take $T$ to be unbounded with respect to its norm. In the context of this question, one could otherwise think that there are already two norms defined on $X$, in which case "unbounded" is ambiguous.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks!