# Are equivalence classes of norms that make the space complete unique?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

In my real analysis two class, we are talking about how $C([a,b],R)$ is the space of continuous functions from some real interval $[a,b]$ to the real numbers. We have talked about how a normed space can be considered complete if every Cauchy sequence of functions converges uniformly to a continuous function.
My question is:

*If a normed space is complete wrt some norm. Can you also have a normed space using a norm not equivalent to the first for which the space will still be complete*. When I say the word equivalent I am referring to two norms belonging to the same equivalence class. I am not saying that the norms are defined the same way.

Update: I am mainly interested in the space of continuous functions so any examples using those spaces would be ideal.

If anybody is still reading this look at the comment I left below and see if you can answer it. Thanks math experts!

Comment: The normed spaces of sequences l^3 and l^2 are isomorphic as vector spaces but not as normed spaces. This tells you that there are two non equivalent norms on the vector space l^2 which make it a Banach space.

Comment: Does this imply that there is only one equivalence class of vector space isomorphisms that make the space complete? Like when you said l^2 and l^3 are isomorphic to each other?

Comment: No, not al all. On an infinite dimensional vector space there are many, many, maaaany different equivalence classes of norms that make it a Banach space, and they are not related by linear isomorphsms. In my example, l^2 is a Hilbert space and l^3 is not, so we know that there two norms are not equivalent even after conjugating by a linear isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much. Real analysis can be so confusing at times.

Comment: You sholdl really write an answer with a concrete example of this, with all the details! That'll unconfuse you maximally.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the spaces $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ are not the same: while the sequence $a_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$ is in $\ell^3$, it is not in $\ell^2$.  I understood the spirit of the question to be about two inequivalent complete norms on the same space.  While $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ may be isomorphic as abstract vector spaces, they're not really the same space and I don't see a simple way to impose the $\ell^3$ norm directly on $\ell^2$, for instance.

Comment: @kcd, but they are isomorphic as abstract vector spaces. Pick any isomorphism from l2 to l3 and pull back the norm. That norm on l2 is not equivalent to the l2 norm (not even isomorphic) because one is a Hilbert space and the other one isn't. Of course, both are complete. This is exactly the same argument as the one by D Fischer mentioned in an answer below

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it is also similar to the argument in my answer below, where I use a crazy field isomorphism to put a non-Archimedean absolute value on $\mathbf C$ making it complete and not locally compact. These things are fundamentally not explicit.

Comment: That field somorphism is actually used to prove *real* things, though (mine is just a weird example) I think the first time I saw it used in real life was BBD's faisceaux perverses, iirc.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked a couple of months ago on Mathoverflow: can a field be complete with respect to two inequivalent absolute values?  Besides $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$, there are many other fields complete with respect to a (nontrivial) absolute value: the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbf Q_p$, the "$p$-adic complex numbers" $\mathbf C_p$, the Laurent series fields $F((t))$ with the $t$-adic absolute value, and so on. While $\mathbf Q_p$ is locally compact, like $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$, $F((t))$ is locally compact only when $F$ is a finite field and $\mathbf C_p$ is not locally compact.

Zorn's lemma (the axiom of choice) implies $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf C_p$ are isomorphic as abstract fields, and using such a totally nonexplicit isomorphism to turn the absolute value on $\mathbf C_p$ into an absolute value on $\mathbf C$, we could say the complex numbers are complete with respect to an absolute value other than its usual one and with respect to which it is not locally compact. How strange! It is very nonconstructive. I don't think what you're seeking really occurs in any natural way.

In my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433920/field-complete-with-respect-to-inequivalent-absolute-values) I show a field can't be locally compact for two inequvalent nontrivial absolute values.  On the same page, Arno Fehm points out an old theorem of F. K. Schmidt that shows if a field of characteristic $0$ is complete with respect to two inequivalent nonarchimedean absolute values then it must be algebraically closed.
So the fact that my example above uses $\mathbf C$ is not a surprise: Schmidt's theorem says any example in characteristic $0$ has to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not unique in general.

There is a nice answer by Daniel Fischer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613034/can-a-vector-space-be-complete-for-two-non-compatible-norms). It is a bit more complicated than you would think by reading the comments above.